# vpnbook connected but IP not changed

Tags: vpn

I'm using OpenVPN GUI v7 in Windows 7 and I downloaded the profile for vpnbook-euro1.
The vpn is connecting, but my IP is not changed.
In the network and sharing center I have a new *Unidentified network* with *No internet access*.
I also started OpenVPN GUI with Administrator rights.

This is the output of `ipconfig`:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 5:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bdb7:754f:a24:1f4%31
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.1.86
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:2f0e:d462:c500:d52f:97b3:2b5c:a19a
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:2f0e:d462:c500:7da3:962b:6046:a59
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d52f:97b3:2b5c:a19a%21
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.102
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%21
                                   192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your VPN isn't pushing a default route, so while its connected your computer wont use it except for accessing 10.x addresses.

Edit you config to include

```
redirect-gateway local def1
```

This will tell openvpn to add a route so that your traffic goes over the VPN and not straight to the internet when the VPN is connected. You may also have to add a line for DNS too.

Comment: This worked. But only for vpnbook-euro1-tcp80. And the assigned IP address reported by OpenVPN GUI is different than the one reported by online IP check tools (but I guess that's normal). And for vpnbook-euro1-udp53 and -udp25000 it doesn't work at all - I get timeout while accessing any web page.

Comment: Worked for me too. I was trying to configure "OpenVPN Connect" for Android

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the OpenVPN GUI with admin privileges. In start menu right click and select run as administrator. Without admin rights it connects but can not change your network settings.

Comment: Did that already. I also updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect an old thread but it's on point for me having recently set things up. OpenVPN has a separate config for each VPNBook connection, so if you fix it for Euro1-tcp80 it only works for Euro1-tcp80. You must edit all of your config files to have it work for other gateway points and ports.